# How to remove ROWGUID designation on a PK column/key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to strip a database of its current UID pks (while retaining the column) as part of a conversion process which will use all int keys.

SSMS 2008 (SQL Express 2008) - Database originally created in SQL 2000.
SQL 2008 full also installed if it helps.

A number of the tables have a **UID pk** which is **ROWGUID=yes**

It seems the ROWGUID designation is only found in the KEY properties.  I can **turn it off** there but I'd like to do it **as part of a script**.  If I do a SCRIPT TO on the key or the index I don't see anything indicating the column is a rowguid.

SMO still sees the column as a rowguid after the PK is dropped and the key and index no longer shows in SSMS.

I am a TSQL idiot, so feel free to speak slowly and use small words ;-)

Guidance appreciated.  TIA

Answer (score 10):

Did you try:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.<table>
  ALTER COLUMN <column>
  DROP ROWGUIDCOL;
```

If you're going to become proficient with altering tables via script (which is a great idea, since it is source controllable, much more repeatable and far less error-prone than using the UI), I'd bookmark the [ALTER TABLE topic in Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx).

Comment: Blush.  Thanks so much Aaron.  I think I had brain-freeze.  Googled my head off, poked around in ssms and forgot the most basic set of docs.  

DOH!

as a followup - is there a generic way to identify in looping through an entire database where the rowguids are - IOW will I throw an error (and stop looping) if I try to drop a rowguidcol that isn't a rowguidcol?

Comment: Sure, your cursor could use: SELECT table = OBJECT_NAME(object_id), column = name FROM sys.columns WHERE is_rowguidcol = 1; ... TRY/CATCH wouldn't be a bad idea either, in case there are situations where the property can't be dropped.

Comment: Thanks once again, Aaron.  That looks like exactly what I'll need.